# Extended Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $\phi_{\alpha} \in L^{1}(X,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ $\forall \alpha \in [0,1)$ is such that $\alpha \mapsto \phi_{\alpha} (x)$ is continuous $ \forall x \in X$, and $\exists g \in L^{1}(X, \mathfrak{A},\mu)$ with $|\phi_{x}(x)| \leq g(x), \forall x \forall \alpha$, then show that

(1) $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0} \int \phi_{\alpha} d\mu = \int \phi_{0}d\mu$

My try:

Let $\alpha_{k}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha_{k} = 0$ and $\alpha_{k} \in [0,1) \forall k$.

Then $|\phi_{a_{k}}| \leq g(x)$ $\forall k, \forall x$.

$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\alpha_{k}} = \phi_{0}$ and by DCT $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int \phi_{\alpha_{k}} d\mu = \int \phi_{0} d\mu$.

Since by assumption $\alpha \mapsto \phi_{\alpha}(x)$ is continuous $\forall x$, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \phi_{\alpha_{k}} = \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0} \phi_{\alpha}$.

Hence, $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow 0}\int \phi_{\alpha} d\mu = \int \phi_{0} d\mu$.

What do you think about this? Have I missed something? Is it easier to argue by contradiction that if (1) is not valid then $\alpha \mapsto \phi_{\alpha}$ cannot be continuous $\forall x$?

Comment: You used continuity when you said $\lim_{k \to \infty} {\phi_{a_k}} = \phi_0$. The step from considering sequences to going to the continuous limit is just the definition of the continuous limit.